# Deleting a partition marked as active and system

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm trying to delete a primary partition that is marked as both active and system.  Which of these attributes is preventing me from deleting the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active.  You need to unmount (deactivate) the partition before you can delete it.  I'm assuming this is on a drive other than the drive of your operating system! :)

Comment: Hmm.. Even System could be it. If your Windows is installed on C:\ & you try to format or delete C:\ via Windows.. it will not allow you to do so.

Comment: How can I unmount the partition? I tried using Computer Management console but there isn't an option there.

Comment: @Amr - Try using "Deactivate"